# How To Display Two Plots on the Main Panel in a Single-File Shiny App?

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

I am pretty new to Shiny R, and I have been attempting to create a single-file Shiny App utilising the built-in "faithful" tibble/data set. All I want to do is create two plots, displayed in the same main panel beside each other, each of which are controlled by their own seperate slider bar.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(


 titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

 # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
     sliderInput("bins1",
                 "Number of bins:",
                 min = 1,
                 max = 50,
                 value = 30),

  sliderInput("bins2",
              "Number of bins:",
              min = 1,
              max = 10,
              value = 5)
  ),



  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("PLOT",
               fluidRow(
                 column(6, plotOutput("distPlot")),
                 column(6, plotOutput("distPlot2"))

    )
   # splitLayout Alternative
   # fluidRow(
   #   splitLayout(plotOutput("distPlot"), plotOutput("distPlot2"))
   # )

 )
   )
 )
 )
 )


   server <- function(input, output, session) {
   x    <- faithful[, 2] 
   y    <- faithful[, 1]

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({ 

  binsOut1 <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins1 + 1)
  hist(x, breaks = binsOut1, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

   })

 output$distplot2 <- renderPlot({

 binsOut2 <- seq(min(y), max(y), length.out = input$bins2 + 1)
 hist(y, breaks = binsOut2, col= 'blue', border= 'black')

   })

  session$onSessionEnded({
  print("Stop!")
  stopApp   
    }) 
         }



   # Run the application 
     shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, while I can get one plot to display in the main panel, the other one does not display no matter what I do. It does not throw any errors; it just does not show up, with an empty space where the second plot should have been. I have tried both fluidrow and splitlayout, but both will have the same issue of being unable to display the second plot. I am using R Studio, Version "Single Candle." Please help!

Comment: There's an error in your code. While you call the second plot distPlot2 in ui, you're calling distplot2 in server, you have to call EXACTLY the same way. Capital letters matters.

Comment: ARRRGGGH! So simple! I didn't see it at all! Yes, that was the problem - it works now. Thank you!